# Interpolating gaps in uneven scale

Tags: r, statistics

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
   depth time          temp
1       0    1 -1.620339e-02
2      10    1 -7.018468e-02
3      20    1 -4.392311e-02
4      30    1 -2.344012e-02
5      50    1 -1.817276e-02
6      75    1 -6.413543e-03
7     100    1 -6.547729e-02
...
320   700   20  2.285078e-02
```

The depth variable is uneven, e.g.: `0  10  20  30  50  75 100 125 150 200 250 300 400 500 600 700`

I'm trying to create a plot where y = depth, x = time, and the gaps are interpolated and colored by `temp`. If I do:

```
viz <- ggplot(temp_data, aes(time, depth, z = temp))
viz + geom_tile(aes(fill = temp)) + stat_contour()
```

It gets me close, though it has large gaps of unplotted data due to the uneven depth scale. I'd like to interpolate the gaps, but it has been a while since I've used R and I'm having trouble figuring out the best way to accomplish this.

Thanks - any help or advice is much appreciated!

Comment: interpolate linearly? Do you want the depths to cover 0 to 700, by 5?

Comment: `approx(temp_data$temp, n=700)`

Comment: @MatthewPlourde Yes, exactly. Ideally, I want to expand depth to `new.depth <- seq(0,700,5)` and then linearly interpolate `temp` for each of the years in the data such that there is a depth 0:700 with a temperature for each year in the data , which goes from 1 to 20.

Comment: Can you provide a larger sample of your data, say depths 1 to 100 and times 1 to 10? Consider using `dput`.

Comment: @MatthewPlourde Sure, no problem. Here are the data https://gist.github.com/jscarto/db406b6bb208629672ab Thanks for your help with this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your sample data:

```
library(akima)
library(ggplot2)
interped <- with(temp_data, interp(time, depth, temp))
temp_data_interp <- with(interped, 
    data.frame(time=rep(x, length.out=length(z)), depth=rep(y, each=length(y)), temp=as.vector(z))
)
```

Take a look at `?interp` to adjust the number of output x and y values.

Without interpolating, you get the following plot:

```
viz <- ggplot(temp_data, aes(time, depth, z = temp))
viz + geom_tile(aes(fill = temp)) + stat_contour()
```

[image]

After interpolating, you get:

```
viz <- ggplot(temp_data_interp, aes(time, depth, z = temp))
viz + geom_tile(aes(fill = temp)) + stat_contour()
```

[image]